# Phidgets interface kit 8/8/8 with EZ1 sonar sensor and ROS Hydro

Tags: ros, sonar, ros-hydro, phidgets

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I implemented a c++ code with phidgets interface kit and the ez1 sonar sensor to be used as collision avoidance on a robot. But I'm having trouble creating the package or somehow building my code with ROS hydro.
So far I used catkin to build the examples for the tutorial as well as building this package : http://wiki.ros.org/phidgets_drivers with success but as far as I understood the package is only for phidgets_ir and phidgets_imu.

Should I try to adjust the package mentioned above or look for something more specific?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199746/phidgets-interface-kit-8/8/8-with-ez1-sonar-sensor-and-ros-hydro/) by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) on ROS Answers with karma: 290 on 2014-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved: had to add "phidget21" on the target_link_libraries section of the CMakeLists.txt file of the package.

---

Originally posted by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) with karma: 290 on 2014-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1